# Как создать временный файл и работать с ним в Python?

Tags: python

Прохожу курс на Coursera, есть задача создать временное хранилище для хранения данных в формате json. Написал скрипт, у меня все работает, загружаю на сервер - не работает, выдает ошибку: 
Ваш скрипт завершился с ошибкой FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/storage.data'
Читал документацию по модулю tempfile, не понял. 
Создаю файл так:

```
storage_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'storage.data')
```

создается файл storage_path.
Потом открываю:

```
with open(storage_path, mode='w', encoding='utf8') as file:
```

и дальше записываю, считываю и т.д.
Но на сервере это не работает. Подскажите что я делаю не так.
[код в песочнице](http://pythontutor.ru/visualizer/saved/3ad0eaba5c/)

Comment: Почему не mkdtemp или mkstemp?

Comment: На какой строке кода получаете эту ошибку? Лучше всего привести в вопросе полный текст `error traceback`

Comment: `os.path.join()` никаких файлов не создаёт. Эта функция со строками/путями работает. `with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile('w', encoding='utf-8') as file:`

Comment: Ну так у вас на компьютере есть нужная директория, а на сервере нет